# WiX: Rollback on update/uninstall not working

Tags: .net, wix

We have a built a custom .NET-based installer for one of our products using WiX, and we are currently trying to implement a "Cancel" button that is shown while the installation is running. When this button is clicked the installation should be rolled back before the application terminates.

I initiate the rollback by setting e.Result to Result.Cancel in the method called by the bootstrapper upon the Progress event. This works fine when installing the application for the first time. However, when I cancel while doing an update or uninstall of the application, the application always ends up being uninstalled (the application's files are deleted).

The update is initiated by calling Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Install) and I am wondering if this is the reason why the application ends up being uninstalled when I cancel during an update (however, this would not explain why cancelling the uninstall does not work correctly :/ ). I tried using LaunchAction.UpdateReplace instead, but I don't get it to work. I have read that in order to use UpdateReplace, one has to call Engine.SetUpdate() first. Since I want the update to occur from the same exe file that the user executed, I tried calling it as follows:

```
Engine.SetUpdate(null, null, 0, UpdateHashType.None, null);
```

But in the log file I get the same errors as when I use UpdateReplace without calling SetUpdate():

```
[21A0:1C1C][2013-12-23T11:44:51]e000: Error 0x8000ffff: Invalid package type.
[21A0:1C1C][2013-12-23T11:44:51]e000: Error 0x8000ffff: Failed to plan execute package.
[21A0:1C1C][2013-12-23T11:44:51]e000: Error 0x8000ffff: Failed to process update package.
[21A0:1C1C][2013-12-23T11:44:51]e000: Error 0x8000ffff: Failed to plan update.
```

I have observed that when I run the .MSI file directly (instead of the custom exe installer), and I cancel the upgrade while it is running, it seems to rollback properly. Hence it looks like the configuration in the .wxs file is fine.

Please advise if I am on the right path and how I should get the rollback to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, did not work rollback on update/uninstall.
I fixed this by setting the cache properties of the MSI package to "yes".

```
<MsiPackage Id="SomeId" DisplayName="Name" SourceFile="Source" Cache="yes"/>
```

Cache="yes" - is a default behavior, but in my project it was set to "no".